# How can i model a GLM for habitat preference?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

So I am using a GLM for binomial distribution to predict seasonality on habitat preference. My model has 2 categorical variables:

"Season" (1, 2), and "habitat" (1,2). But when I try to run the model, I only get 2 coefficients shown where I believe i should get 4. Im so confused right now.

Also I have heterogeneity in my effort. I got this data using camera traps. So I have cameras that worked more days than others, how to implement this in the model?